# How to show $f(z)=x^2+y^2+i2xy$ is differentiable at $z_0=x_0+i0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show $f(z)=x^2+y^2+i2xy$ is differentiable at $z=x_0+i0$? Here is what I have done we know by the Cauchy Riemann (its it very easy to verify) that these can only hold for $z_0=x_0+i0$ that is along the real line.

Now to use the definition to prove it is differentiable at $z_0=0$

We have $$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+w)-f(z_0)}{w}$$ letting $w=u+iv$ we get

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{f((x_0+u)+iv)-f(x_0)}{w}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{(x_0+u)^2+v^2+2(x_0+u)vi-x_0^2}{w}$$ I want to be able to cancel the $w$ somehow but I'm not quite sure how to do it, in similar examples I have seen using the squeeze rule or properties of complex numbers to get rid of the $w$ and finish the question but I can't see how here?

Could anyone show me how to finish it?

Comment: Your second sentence is incomplete. "... we know by the Cauchy Riemann.." (then what?)

Comment: Expanding $(x_0+u)^2$, one sees that the ratio is $$\frac{2x_0(u+iv)+u^2+v^2+2uvi}w=2x_0+u+iv\left(\frac{\bar w}w\right),$$ whose limit when $w=u+iv\to0$ should be clear.

Comment: If you want to prove it by *definition*, there is nothing to do with the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Okay I think I have it thank you the limit is $2x_0$ right? And I know it has nothing to do with C-R that was just my thought process and showing the derivative can only exist along real line.

Comment: @Did can you show how you go from left hand to right hand in equality above please?

Comment: Use $w=u+iv$ to factor $w$ as much as possible in the numerator of the LHS and contemplate what is left.

Comment: Do you want to show it is differentiable at 0? Then also $x_0 = 0$. Anyway, the notation is a bit confusing with the $u's,v's,w's$ and $x_0's$. I have set up the problem using a bit different notation here (although not doing all the work for you!) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796593/show-using-the-definition-that-f-is-differentiable-at-x-0i0/1797589#1797589

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show $f(z) - z^2$ has the property.